# Laravel Eloquent : retrieving an unique value with belongsToMany relationship

Tags: eloquent

With Eloquent I'm having an hard time achieving a relationship between three tables:

`t_orders` lists all the orders and the customer_id related to

```
+----------+-------------+
| order_id | customer_id |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |           5 |
|        2 |           3 |
|        3 |           1 |
+----------+-------------+
```

`t_orders_items` lists the items (fabrication_orders) of each order

```
+----------+-------------------+
| order_id | fabrication_order |
+----------+-------------------+
|        1 |                 1 |
|        1 |                 2 |
|        2 |                 3 |
|      ... |               ... |
+----------+-------------------+
```

Finally `t_customer` table giving me some info about the customers

```
+-------------+---------------+
| customer_id | customer_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | Foo           |
|           3 | Bar           |
|           5 | Fun           |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I simply want to know for a given `fabrication_order`(always unique) the associated client name. So with `fabrication_order` = 2 I would get `Fun`.

Reading Eloquent's documentation I thought `t_orders` would play somehow the role of a pivot table.

So I wrote the following relationship:

```
class OrderItem extends Model
{
    ...
    public function customer(){
        return
            $this->belongsToMany('App\Customer', 't_orders','order_id',
            'customer_id', 'order_id', 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

The unique downside is that it returns a collection instead of a unique value.

```
"customer":[{"customer_id":5,"customer_name":"Fun"..}]
```

I wish to achieve :

```
"customer":{"customer_id":5,"customer_name":"Fun"..}
```

Off course the collection has just one value but I wanted to write things cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two separate `BelongsTo` relationships:

`OrderItem` → `Order`, `Order` → `Customer`

Then access the customer like this:

```
$orderItem->order->customer
```

If you need it as an attribute in the JSON string:

```
class OrderItem extends Model
{
    $appends = ['customer'];

    public function getCustomerAttribute() {
        return $this->order->customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Order` → `Customer` will be in the Order Model is it so?